# Is there an equivalent of sbt-start-script for maven?

Tags: java, maven

I've previously used this plugin for sbt: sbt-start-script (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script). Is there an equivalent tool for maven? I want something that I can run on the command line that will execute my java program, with the correct classpath. sbt-start-script does this by generating a shell script for me that I execute on the command line like this:

```
./target/start
```

Inside that shell script, it basically has a call to

```
java -cp xxxx example.Main
```

where xxx is the full classpath on my machine.

I know I can use maven to execute my java program directly with

```
mvn -Dexec.mainClass="example.Main"
```

but that executes it within the same JVM as maven. I'm interested in starting my program with its own jvm.

I don't want to pack my whole project and all its dependencies into one executable jar file, I'd rather use the classpath that maven knows about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I think I can write this script by hand that does the right thing:

```
#!/bin/bash

# directory of this script
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

mvn -o -f $DIR/pom.xml -q dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile="$DIR/target/classpath.txt"

java -cp $DIR/target/classes:`cat $DIR/target/classpath.txt` example.Main $@
exitcode=$?
exit $exitcode
```

This seems to work, but I had to write it by hand. sbt-start-script generates a script much like this, every time I build. I'm still interested if anyone has any better solutions to this.

Comment: deleting my answer to remove duplication because you implemented the same way and added details, +1